# Windows 8 hardware acceleration requiremetns

Tags: windows-8, graphics-card, hardware-acceleration

I'd like to upgrade my graphics card -- It's old and only has 500mb of memory.

It does not support hardware acceleration for Windows (8), and I would like to make sure the replacement does.

So I'd like to know what the minimum requirements are for hardware acceleration, however my google-foo has come up utterly short.

My motherboard is an Asus P5K and uses PCIe v2.x for the interface.

Comment: Anything on the market and recently released would meet your requirements. We cannot recommend specific graphic cards.

Comment: @Ramhound: I didn't ask for specific card recommendations. I asked about minimum *requirements* on Windows 8 (e.g. ram?). I hope you didn't down-vote me for that.

Comment: There are no specific requirements if there are specific requirements they would be listed on Microsoft's website and they are not.  I don't really find this question helpful.  As I indicated any new product would support it.

Answer (score 0):

Directly from Microsoft. [Graphics card: Microsoft DirectX 9 graphics device with WDDM driver](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/system-requirements)

```
 Any thing new certainly AMD Radeon R5, R7, or R9   Nvidia 700 series
 Probably Radeon 7000 series or Nvidia 600 series
```

Numerous old cards could possibly work, but the older you get the worst performance and you start to lose features like DirectX 11 support.  If you are a gamer DirectX is important to you, otherwise never mind.

Instead of making a decision based on Windows 8 performance alone why not compare video cards and pick one that will be as fast as you need it to be.

[Tomshardware Performance Charts highest to lowest](http://www.tomshardware.com/charts/2013-vga-gpgpu/01-3DMark11-B-Performance,2932.html)